# Sum all values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sum all the values in a dataframe into one number.

So for example with the dataframe

```
            BBG.XAMS.FUR.S_pnl_pos_cost  BBG.XAMS.MT.S_pnl_pos_cost
date                                                               
2015-03-23                    -0.674996                   -0.674997
2015-03-24                    82.704951                   11.868748
2015-03-25                   -11.027327                   84.160210
2015-03-26                   228.426675                 -131.901556
2015-03-27                   -99.744986                  214.579858
```

I would like the value 377.71658 returned.

I have tried df.sum() but that only sums by column.

Comment: `print(df.sum().sum())?`

Comment: Granted that there must be a solution that sums both columns as a single action, what's wrong with adding the sums for each column together as a second step?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to sum all values in a Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733477/whats-the-best-way-to-sum-all-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 19):

I would do

```
>>> df.values.sum()
377.71658000000002
```

which drops down to the underlying numpy array, and is likely to be the fastest, if the frame is all-numeric.  But there are lots of other options:

```
>>> %timeit df.values.sum()
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.27 µs per loop
>>> %timeit df.sum().sum()
10000 loops, best of 3: 109 µs per loop
>>> %timeit df.unstack().sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 233 µs per loop
>>> %timeit df.stack().sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 190 µs per loop
```

Comment: Notice this fails if you have NaN as a value. You could replace NaN with zeros. df.fillna(0).values.sum()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733477/whats-the-best-way-to-sum-all-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 6):

Just sum the column sums:

```
df.sum().sum()
```

Or for better performance:

```
np.nansum(df)
```

Note that you need to use [`nansum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html) to treat NaNs as zeroes for the purpose of summing them.

Timings:

```
# Create dataframe with 1m rows and 100 columns.
np.random.seed(0)
rows = 1_000_000
cols = 100
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(rows, cols))
# Add one thousand NaNs.
for row, col in zip(np.random.randint(0, rows, 1000),
                    np.random.randint(0, cols, 1000)):
    df.iat[row, col] = np.nan

%timeit np.nansum(df)
# 274 ms ± 3.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df.fillna(0).to_numpy().sum()
# 974 ms ± 3.97 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df.sum().sum()
# 1.04 s ± 3.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> df.to_numpy().sum()
nan

>>> np.nansum(df)
5965.87530314851
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733477/whats-the-best-way-to-sum-all-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 2):

If data-frame contains non-numeric data, and want to just get sum of integers, do:

```
df.sum(numeric_only=True).sum()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733477/whats-the-best-way-to-sum-all-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

To sum of integer/float columns in a dataframe use the below query:

```
df.sum()
```

To find the sum of a particular column values you can use column index:

```
d = df.sum()
d[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
np.array(df.iloc[:,1:).sum()
```