# What's the best way to sum all values in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, sum

I figured out these two methods.  Is there a better one?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5, 6, 7], 'B': [7, 8, 9]})
>>> print df.sum().sum()
42
>>> print df.values.sum()
42
```

Just want to make sure I'm not missing something more obvious.

Comment: Be careful, because if there are `nan` values `df.sum().sum()` ignores the `nan` and returns a `float` whereas `df.values.sum()` returns `nan`. So the 2 methods are not equivalent.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

#### Updated for Pandas 0.24+

```
df.to_numpy().sum()
```

---

#### Prior to Pandas 0.24+

```
df.values
```

Is the underlying numpy array

```
df.values.sum()
```

Is the numpy sum method and is faster

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I thought!

Comment: Is it faster purely because one function calls the other or is there some more fundamental difference?

Comment: @kuanb two reasons.  One,  `df.values.sum()` is a `numpy` operation and most of the time, `numpy` is more performant.  Two, `numpy` sums over all elements in an array regardless of dimensionality.  `pandas` requires two separate calls to `sum` one for each dimension.

Answer (score 6):

Adding some numbers to support this:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
import timeit
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(int(1e6)).reshape(500000, 2), columns=list("ab"))

def pandas_test():
    return df['a'].sum()

def numpy_test():
    return df['a'].to_numpy().sum()

timeit.timeit(numpy_test, number=1000)  # 0.5032469799989485
timeit.timeit(pandas_test, number=1000)  # 0.6035906639990571
```

So we get a 20% performance on my machine just for Series summations!

Comment: But is `df['a'].sum()` the same as `df['a'].to_numpy().sum()`?  I think `df['a'].sum()` only sums the columns doesn't it?

Comment: yeah, this is just comparison for a sigle series smmation, I wasn't summing the whole df

Comment: Oh I see.  But this question is about summing the whole dataframe, not one series.

Comment: Can you report your pandas and numpy versions?  I get a much bigger speed difference on your tests with Pandas 0.24.2 and Numpy 1.16.2.