# Pandas: Summing all elements in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a Pandas dataframe `df`, we can sum the columns like this

```
[x for x in df.sum()]
```

and produce the sum of sums like this.

```
sum([x for x in df.sum()])
```

Can this be done using only dataframe operations, without resorting to Python's sum()?

Comment: `df.sum().sum()`

Comment: this was already asked and answered. Should have looked into [sum of sum of dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733477/whats-the-best-way-to-sum-all-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can do `stack`

```
df.stack().sum()
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `np.sum`:

```
np.sum(df.to_numpy())
```

or as @jakub points out:

```
df.to_numpy().sum()
```

*Timings:*

Using...

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10000).reshape(100,-1))

%timeit df.to_numpy().sum()
# 12.1 µs ± 357 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.sum(df.to_numpy())
# 14 µs ± 263 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit df.stack().sum()
# 469 µs ± 30.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.sum().sum()
# 381 µs ± 21.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: equivalently `df.to_numpy().sum()`