# Find minimum of the entire dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataFrame` like:

```
    a  b
0   4  7
1   3  2
2   1  9
3   3  4
4   2  Nan
```

I need to calculate `min, mean, std, sum`, for ***all*** dataFrame as a single list of numbers. (e.g minimum here is 1)

**EDIT: The data may have Nans or different size columns.**

```
df.to_numpy().mean()
```

Produce `Nan`, because there are nans in the arrays and they have different length.

How to calculate all normal math stuff on ***all of these*** numbers ?

Comment: Did you try something like `df['a'].to_numpy().concat(df['b'].to_numpy())`. I am not sure if it's work but I think youg et the spirit.

Comment: yes but the lists are different sizes and have Nan inside. So results are completely wrong.

Comment: I also did tried profits.to_numpy().mean() which produce Nan.

Comment: This question is similar to this one and so the answers there may help: [What's the best way to sum all values in a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38733477/1609514)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pandas` solution is with reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Series.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.aggregate.html):

```
def std_ddof0(x):
    return x.std(ddof=0)

out = df.stack().agg(['mean','sum',std_ddof0, 'min'])
print (out)
mean          3.888889
sum          35.000000
std_ddof0     2.424158
min           1.000000
dtype: float64
```

`Numpy` solution with [`np.nanmean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html), [`np.nansum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html), [`np.nanstd`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanstd.html), [`np.nanmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmin.html):

```
totalp = df.to_numpy().reshape(-1)

out = np.nanmean(totalp), np.nansum(totalp), np.nanstd(totalp), np.nanmin(totalp)
print (out)
(3.888888888888889, 35.0, 2.4241582476968255, 1.0)
```

Another idea is remove missing values first:

```
totalp = df.to_numpy().reshape(-1)
totalp = totalp[~np.isnan(totalp)]
print (totalp)
[4. 7. 3. 2. 1. 9. 3. 4. 2.]

out = np.mean(totalp), np.sum(totalp), np.std(totalp), np.min(totalp)
print (out)
(3.888888888888889, 35.0, 2.4241582476968255, 1.0)
```

Comment: thanks (again) ! you always have the easiest solutios.