# Converting R apply function to Python

Tags: python, numpy, apply

I'm in the process of converting my existing R code to Python as a way to teach myself, but I've run into something that I can't seem to crack.

Here's a example of the R code which works as expected

```
var <- 0.08

a <- data.frame(a = runif(10, 0, 1), 
                b = runif(10, 0, 1), 
                c = runif(10, 0, 1), 
                d = runif(10, 0, 1))

b <- data.frame(a = c(0,4,6,8,10,12,12,14,16,18), 
                b = c(2,6,8,10,12,14,14,16,18,20), 
                c = c(4,8,10,12,14,16,16,18,20,22),
                d = c(6,10,12,14,16,18,18,20,22,24))

output <- data.table(total = seq(0, 10))

output[total%%2==0, prob:= apply(output[total%%2==0], 1, function(x) { sum(a[, 1:4] * (b[, 1:4]==x[1]))})]
output[total%%2==1, prob:= apply(output[total%%2==1], 1, function(x) { sum(a[, 1:4] * (b[, 1:4]==(x[1]-1))) * var/(1-var)})]
```

and here's what I tried in Python which is returning 'nan' fields in the 'prob' column

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

var = 0.08

a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(10, 4)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

b = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 12, 14, 16, 18],
                  'b': [2, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 14, 16, 18, 20],
                  'c': [4, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 16, 18, 20, 22],
                  'd': [6, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 18, 20, 22, 24]})

output = pd.DataFrame({'total': range(0, 11)})

output.loc[output['total'] % 2 == 0, 'prob'] = output[output['total'] % 2 == 0].apply(lambda x: np.sum(a.iloc[:, 0:4] * (b.iloc[:, 0:4] == x[0])), axis=1)
output.loc[output['total'] % 2 == 1, 'prob'] = output[output['total'] % 2 == 1].apply(lambda x: np.sum(a.iloc[:, 0:4] * (b.iloc[:, 0:4] == (x[0] - 1))) * var / (1 - var), axis=1)
```

any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Please explain in details the logic of the R code? Also provide the expected output (use `np.random.seed(0)` to make your input reproducible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is some of the things you will need to learn when migrating R code to Python code. In R you know the sum of the values of a `data.frame` will sum every element, this is not the case with `pandas`. For example, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733477/whats-the-best-way-to-sum-all-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe).

By default when you call `sum` in a `DataFrame` it will sum across the rows, not all values. What you end up having is a `Series` in each element of the `DataFrame` you use `apply`, when in fact you were expecting a single value. You can test this if you print each iteration.

```py
output.loc[output['total'] % 2 == 0, 'prob'] = output[output['total'] % 2 == 0].apply(
    lambda x: print(np.sum(a.iloc[:, 0:4] * (b.iloc[:, 0:4] == x[0]))),
    axis = 1
)
```

You will see a bunch of `Series`. The solution to your problem is to sum again the values for the `Series`, or convert the `DataFrame` into an `numpy.array`.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

var = 0.08

a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(10, 4)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

b = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 12, 14, 16, 18],
                  'b': [2, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 14, 16, 18, 20],
                  'c': [4, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 16, 18, 20, 22],
                  'd': [6, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 18, 20, 22, 24]})

output = pd.DataFrame({'total': range(0, 11)})

output.loc[output['total'] % 2 == 0, 'prob'] = output[output['total'] % 2 == 0].apply(
    lambda x: np.sum(a.iloc[:, 0:4] * (b.iloc[:, 0:4] == x[0])).sum(),
    axis = 1
)

output.loc[output['total'] % 2 == 1, 'prob'] = output[output['total'] % 2 == 1].apply(
    lambda x: np.sum(a.iloc[:, 0:4] * (b.iloc[:, 0:4] == (x[0] - 1))).sum() * var / (1 - var),
    axis = 1
)

output
```

|  | total | prob |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0.503596 |
| 1 | 1 | 0.0437909 |
| 2 | 2 | 0.20748 |
| 3 | 3 | 0.0180417 |
| 4 | 4 | 0.666049 |
| 5 | 5 | 0.0579173 |
| 6 | 6 | 1.35971 |
| 7 | 7 | 0.118235 |
| 8 | 8 | 1.33156 |
| 9 | 9 | 0.115787 |
| 10 | 10 | 2.5496 |

Which I guess is what you want. You should definitely provide the desired output in further questions as it make much easier to help that way.